# What directory does Spring serve views from?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What directory does Spring 4 serve content from by default, and how can I change this?  I'm using Spring Tool Suite, and I generated this project using *New->Spring Project* in the top toolbar.

Here is a list of my current directory set up..I can't seem to place home.jsp in the right place so it serves the pages - I keep getting a 404.

Here is the code for my controller:

[image]

And my current directory structure:

[image]

What are the best practices for this sort of thing?  How can I get this to function properly?

Answer (score 2):

Spring looks for views in the location you specify in your configuration, namely in the definition of `ViewResolver` bean. So to get Spring to register views, which are in `/WEB-INF/views` in your case, you must have following bean in your Spring config:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

or if you are using Java config:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

After you specify this configuration your views should be correctly resolved.

You can also return absolute location of the view from your controller method, if you don't want to configure ViewResolver:

```
return "/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp"
```